# SQL Query produces duplicates with "Where IN" query

Tags: sql-server

I have a large SQL statement which does a whole load of joins on my tables.  I have converted some of my table relationships to **many-to-many** relationships so that it is more efficient.  I have therefore decided to convert my SQL to do a `WHERE IN` statement (on location).

The following query is the one that *currently* returns the desired results:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMemberListing]
@Locations nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 
    Member.Id,
    AspNetUsers.Salutation,
    AspNetUsers.FirstName,
    AspNetUsers.PhotoUrl,
    AspNetUsers.LastName,
    AspNetUsers.Birthday,
    AspNetUsers.Gender,
    Member.IDType,
    Member.JoinDate,
    CONCAT (AspNetUsers.FirstName, ' ', AspNetUsers.LastName) as FullName,
    AspNetUsers.CountryCode,
    AspNetUsers.Email,
    Location.Name as LocationName,
    AspNetUsers.HomePhone as HomePhone,
    coalesce(Package.Name,'No Package') as PackageName, 
    PackageTerm = case when Package.PackageIsReoccuring = 1 then 'Recurring' when Package.PackageIsSession = 1 then 'Paid In Full' when membership.TotalPrice = 0 then 'Free' when Package.PackagePayInFull = 1 then 'Paid In Full' end,
    PackageType.Name as PackageType,
    MembershipId = case when membership.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 0 end,
    coalesce(membershipstate.name, 'N/A') as MembershipState,
    MembershipStartDate = case when membership.StartDate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.StartDate) end,
    MembershipEndDate = case when membership.EndDate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.EndDate) end
from
(
    select
        member.id as memberid,
        (
            select top 1 id 
            from membership 
            where memberid = member.id 
                and membership.StartDate <= getdate()
            order by membership.enddate desc
        ) as membershipid
    from member
) as LatestMembership
left join membership
    on latestmembership.membershipid = membership.id
join member 
    on latestmembership.memberid = member.id
join AspNetusers 
    on member.AspNetUserId = AspNetUsers.Id
join Location 
    on member.HomeLocationId = Location.Id
left join Package 
    on membership.packageid = package.Id
left join PackageType 
    on package.packagetypeid = packagetype.Id
left join MembershipState 
    on membership.membershipstateid = membershipstate.Id
Order By aspNetusers.LastName desc
END
```

Below is what i have tried to do; however, it is duplicating the otherwise correct results based on the number of values in the `WHERE IN` join.

This `on member.HomeLocationId = Location.Id`
becomes     `on member.HomeLocationId IN (SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@Locations, ','))`

As seen below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMemberListing]
    @Locations nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select 
    Member.Id,
        AspNetUsers.Salutation,
        AspNetUsers.FirstName,
        AspNetUsers.PhotoUrl,
        AspNetUsers.LastName,
        AspNetUsers.Birthday,
        AspNetUsers.Gender,
        Member.IDType,
        Member.JoinDate,
        CONCAT (AspNetUsers.FirstName, ' ', AspNetUsers.LastName) as FullName,
        AspNetUsers.CountryCode,
        AspNetUsers.Email,
        Location.Name as LocationName,
        AspNetUsers.HomePhone as HomePhone,
        coalesce(Package.Name,'No Package') as PackageName, 
        PackageTerm = case when Package.PackageIsReoccuring = 1 then 'Recurring' when Package.PackageIsSession = 1 then 'Paid In Full' when membership.TotalPrice = 0 then 'Free' when Package.PackagePayInFull = 1 then 'Paid In Full' end,
        PackageType.Name as PackageType,
        MembershipId = case when membership.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 0 end,
        coalesce(membershipstate.name, 'N/A') as MembershipState,
        MembershipStartDate = case when membership.StartDate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.StartDate) end,
        MembershipEndDate = case when membership.EndDate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.EndDate) end
    from
    (
        select member.id as memberid,
            (
                select top 1 id 
                from membership 
                where memberid = member.id 
                and membership.StartDate <= getdate()
                order by membership.enddate desc
            ) as membershipid
        from member
    ) as LatestMembership
    left join membership 
        on latestmembership.membershipid = membership.id
    join member 
        on latestmembership.memberid = member.id
    join AspNetusers 
        on member.AspNetUserId = AspNetUsers.Id
    join Location 
        on member.HomeLocationId IN (SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@Locations, ','))
    left join Package 
        on membership.packageid = package.Id
    left join PackageType 
        on package.packagetypeid = packagetype.Id
    left join MembershipState 
        on membership.membershipstateid = membershipstate.Id
    Order By aspNetusers.LastName desc
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to using your split function in the where clause. Don't use that function in the join.

In addition you don't really have a valid join condition on the locations table go back to this

```
on member.HomeLocationId = Location.Id
```

And later

```
 Where member.HomeLocationId IN (SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@Locations, ','))
```